# Closure Coercion not working in certain case

Tags: groovy

I'm calling a Java method from Groovy which expects an instance of a SAM interface as a parameter.

Normally Groovy is happy with passing in a closure in these cases, and will coerce it accordingly HOWEVER in this case, the interface extends another one and overrides the single method.

Note - It still only has one method, but it's been overriden.

In this instance Groovy doesn't automatically coerce the closure and the only way I seem to be able to call it is by using "AS".

I'm publishing an API to help kids to learn code and really don't want them to have to use "AS" because it would complicate things.

Here's some code that shows the issue...

**Java**

```
public interface BaseHandler<T> {
    public void handle(T test);
}

public interface Handler extends BaseHandler<String> {
    public void handle(String test);
}

public class LibraryClass {
    public void method(Handler handler) {
        handler.handle("WORLD!");
    }
}
```

**Groovy**

```
LibraryClass bar = new LibraryClass();
bar.method({ name -> println "HELLO " + name})
```

**Error**

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Bar.doIt() is applicable for argument types: (testClosures$_run_closure1) values: [testClosures$_run_closure1@fe63b60]
```

Any help on how to get around this without using "AS" would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy wants to implement the interface by coercion, but doesn't know which interface method it should implement. As there are 2:
the handle(String test) and a second one: handle(String test) (of the baseHandler)

The solution is to remove the handle(String test) from the handler (it adds nothing as the BaseHandler posesses this method already thanks to the generics).

Like this it works correctly:

```
public interface BaseHandler<T> {
    public void handle(T test);
}

public interface Handler extends BaseHandler<String> {

}

public class LibraryClass {
    public void method(Handler handler) {
        handler.handle("WORLD!");
    }
}
```